# SAS - Choose last dataset in library that satisfies specific name convention

Tags: sas, sas-macro

Say I have the a library named `mylib`.

Within the `mylib` library, the following datasets are held:

```
mylib.data_yearly_2015
mylib.data_yearly_2016
mylib.data_yearly_2017
mylib.data_yearly_2018
mylib.data_yearly_2015
mylib.data_mtly_01JUN2015
mylib.data_mtly_01DEC2015
mylib.data_mtly_01JUN2016
mylib.data_mtly_01DEC2016
mylib.data_mtly_01JUN2017
mylib.data_mtly_01DEC2017
```

Now I need to write a macro that will specifically choose the latest `data_mtly_xxxxxx` table from the `mylib` library.

For example, in the current stage, it should choose `mylib.data_mtly_01DEC2017`

If, however, a new dataset gets added, for example `mylib.data_mtly_01JUN2018`, it would have to choose that table.

How can I go about doing this in SAS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Get a list of all data sets
2. Get the date portion using SCAN() and INPUT()
3. Get max date.

   ```
   Proc sql noprint;

   Select max(input(scan(name, -1, ‘_’), date9.) ) into :latest_date
   From sashelp.vtable
   Where upcase(libname) = ‘MYLIB’ and upcase(memname) like ‘DATA_MTLY_%’;

   Quit;
   ```

Now you should have the latest date value in a macro variable and can use that in your code.

```
   %put &latest_date.;
```

If it looks like a number and not a date, you’ll need a format applied but you should be able to convert it using PUT().

Note: code is untested.